# .bashrc; create alias, permissions problems

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, alias

Today I created a new alias in `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias upgrade='aptitude update && aptitude full-upgrade -y'
```

but when I run `upgrade`, it shows:

```
E: Could not open the lock file "/var/lib/apt/lists/lock" - open (13: Permission denied) 
E: Could not lock /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

I tried putting:

```
alias upgrade='sudo aptitude update && aptitude full-upgrade -y'
```

but I have the same error, and I try running:

```
sudo upgrade
```

but I have the same error. How can I solve this?

If you need more information, tell me.

Answer (score 3):

Your alias must contain `sudo` twice, one inn front of each of the two commands you combined using `&&`:

```
alias upgrade='sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude full-upgrade -y'
```

Alternatively you could start a subshell with `sudo` which runs both commands internally:

```
alias upgrade='sudo bash -c "aptitude update && aptitude full-upgrade -y"'
```